# React Structured Data with graphql query

Tags: reactjs, graphql, schema

Has anyone tried to implement this in a react project? There is not much in the documentation on the github/npm website. When I am trying to inject data is there a specific way to add graphql data?

JSX:

```
<JSONLD>
  <Generic jsonldtype="event" schema={{
    name: "${adv_event.title}", 
    description: "${adv_event.body}",
    startDate: "YYYY-MM-DDT:HH:MM",
    endDate: "YYYY-MM-DDT:HH:MM",
    image: "",
  }}>
    <Generic type="location" jsonldtype="Place" schema={{ name: "test", }}/>
  </Generic>       
</JSONLD>
```

What I have tried:

```
name: "${adv_event.title}", 

name: "`${adv_event.title}`", 

name: {adv_event.title},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to delete the post but, if any others are looking for this question in the future:

Answer is

```
name: `${adv_event.title}`,
```

Comment: Advise if I should delete or keep